# Is it possible to call a post-deserialization method after Apache CXF deserializes object from SOAP?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I am using Apache CXF to provide a SOAP webservice. Is there a way that I can configure the CXF deserialization to call a method on the newly deserialized object to update some internal state?

Specifically, the object needs to build some lists once it has been deserialized from the SOAP request.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [Interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) and gain access to your newly deserialized object.

Like that:

```
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;

public class PreInvokeInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public PreInvokeInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
            MessageContentsList mcl = message.getContent(MessageContentsList.class);
            YourObject obj = (YourObject) mcl.get(0);
            obj.updateInternalState();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sort of works, but there are some issues:  1) `calling.getContent(MyObj.class)` with the class of the object I actually want, returns null. In debugger, I can see that the object I want is contained within a `MessageContentsList` instance in the Message.contents array.  I had to change code to `message.getContent(List.class)`, and then retrieve first item in the MessageContentsList.  2) There are 2 different web methods where this object can be sent.  The second method receives a list of these objects. So it requires a different interceptor for the method receiving a List of the objects.

Comment: You are write about the MessageContentsList. When I wrote the answer I were at home without access to the real code (a interceptor) I use at work. About the method, you can check which method is been invoked with message.getExchange().getBindingOperationInfo().getOperationInfo(). Maybe you don't need a second interceptor.

Comment: I did actually use the getOperationInfo() as you suggested. However, using the Interceptor seems not a good fit to solve the problem. What I imagine a better design for CXF would be to give us an interface to implement which has a standard post-deserialization method.  Using an Interceptor is overly complicated. (For now, I just added a single line of code in the method which is processing the received object - since that is the "simplest thing which could work".)

Comment: I agree with you. I personally don't like this kind of interceptor chain architecture that CXF adopt. But it is the only way I know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAXB, you could use [Unmarshaller.Listener.afterUnmarshal](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html#afterUnmarshal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to get ahold of an object after it has been unmarshalled from XML.  You will need to write a class that implements the Unmarshaller.Listener interface, and then use CXF's [JAXBDataBinding.setUnmarshallerListener](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxb/JAXBDataBinding.html#setUnmarshallerListener%28javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.Listener%29) to register that class as a listener.

This Listener interface is not specific to CXF, and there is a corresponding [Marshaller.Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.Listener.html) interface.